# preencher combobox com dados de outro combobox

Tags: c#, sql

Tenho uma tabela Cidade onde tem os campos nomeCidade, IdEstado, IdPais, alem das tabelas Estado e Pais.
Estou fazendo uma aplicação em c# onde utilizo 3 combobox. Ao selecionar o primeiro combobox (cboCidade) e escolher um registro, quero que seja selecionado na mesma hora, os respectivos estados e paises dos combobox cboEstado e CboPais. Lembrando que os combobox Estado e Pais já estão preenchidos com os respectivos valores das tabelas (Estado e Pais)

Comment: Utilizar o evento `SelectedIndexChanged` no `cboCidade` não resolve seu problema?

Comment: Inclua o seu código à pergunta para podermos indicar a melhor solução dentro do seu cenário.

Comment: a minha duvida está justamente em fazer o codigo. Alem do valor do ValueMenber que o combobox ja retorna, precisaria de outro valor. Teria como isso ??

Answer (score -2):

Nas propriedades do campo cboCidade, selecione o raio, onde permite a configuração dos eventos. Daí, clique 2 x no item SelectedIndexChanged

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele irá abrir essa janela de códigos:

```
private void cboCidade_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Dentro dele, vc insere a consulta SQL para preencher os combos cboEstado e CboPais com base no valor selecionado de cboCidade

Aqui um exemplo:

```
private void cboCidade_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection Conexao = new SqlConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = @"sua string de conexao"
        };
        Conexao.Open();

        //Aqui você trará os Ids de Estado e País, para você preencher os respectivos combos
        string ConsultaSql = string.Concat("SELECT idEstado, idPais FROM Cidade WHERE nomeCidade = '", cboCidade.Text, "';");
        SqlCommand ComandoSQl = new SqlCommand(ConsultaSql, ConexaoSql);
        SqlDataReader LeitorDataReader = ComandoSQl.ExecuteReader();

        int estado = 0;
        int pais = 0;

        while (LeitorDataReader.Read())
        {
            estado = Convert.ToInt32(LeitorDataReader["idEstado"].ToString());
            pais = Convert.ToInt32(LeitorDataReader["idPais"].ToString());
        }
        LeitorDataReader.Close();

        //Aqui você irá preencher o combo estado
        ConsultaSql = string.Concat("SELECT nomeEstado FROM Estado WHERE idEstado = ", estado, ";");
        ComandoSQl = new SqlCommand(ConsultaSql, ConexaoSql);
        LeitorDataReader = ComandoSQl.ExecuteReader();
        cboEstado.Items.Clear();
        cboEstado.Text = string.Empty;

        while (LeitorDataReader.Read())
        {
            cboEstado.Items.Add(LeitorDataReader["nomeEstado"].ToString());
        }
        LeitorDataReader.Close();

        //Aqui você irá preencher o combo pais
        ConsultaSql = string.Concat("SELECT nomePais FROM Pais WHERE idPais = ", pais, ";");
        ComandoSQl = new SqlCommand(ConsultaSql, ConexaoSql);
        LeitorDataReader = ComandoSQl.ExecuteReader();
        cboPais.Items.Clear();
        cboPais.Text = string.Empty;

        while (LeitorDataReader.Read())
        {
            cboEstado.Items.Add(LeitorDataReader["nomePais"].ToString());
        }
        LeitorDataReader.Close();

        ConexaoMySql.Close();

    }
```

Apenas uma observação:
Adapte os objetos SQL de acordo com o seu banco (SQL Server, MySql, etc)